# Ubuntu 22.04 upgrade to linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic fails due to ZFS

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, zfs

When I try to upgrade to the latest kernel image on my 22.04 (System 76) laptop, I get an error unmounting a volume from tmp that appears to be a ZFS volume:

```
$  sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for rotten:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 linux-headers-5.15.0-48
  linux-headers-5.15.0-48-generic linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-generic
  python3-charset-normalizer python3-defusedxml python3-pygments
  python3-requests-toolbelt
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic (5.15.0-53.59) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic (5.15.0-53.59) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-53-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/yellow_carp_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu..........................................................................W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_rlc.bin for module amdgpu........................................................................W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-53-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-53-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-52-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
Found linux image: vmlinuz-5.15.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-48-generic in rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71
umount: /tmp/zfsmnt.IHNzvH: target is busy.
umount: /tmp/zfsmnt.IHNzvH: target is busy.
rmdir: failed to remove '/tmp/zfsmnt.IHNzvH': Device or resource busy
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.15.0-53-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The mount point:

```
$  mount | grep zfsmnt.IHNzvH
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_4nnk71 on /tmp/zfsmnt.IHNzvH type zfs (rw,noatime,xattr,posixacl)
```

I do have encryption enabled, if that matters.

At the moment my laptop reboots cleanly and has no other issues.  I'm just stuck upgrading to the latest image.

I think the amdgpu warnings are a red herring and can be ignored.

Comment: I also notice this in `/var/log/syslog` at about the time the `umount` fails:  ```systemd[1]: tmp-zfsmnt.vsIcBG-boot.mount: Deactivated successfully.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had essentially the same error message as you. The part of the install that was falling over could also be replicated outside of the `apt upgrade` process via `sudo update-grub`.

We took a punt that it could have been related to the recently installed sophos antivirus, so disabled via `sudo systemctl stop sophos-spl.service`. After this the `sudo update-grub` succeeded. As we had been trying other commands to manually remove the old kernel image etc we then did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt --fix-broken install` which got the system back to a happy place.

Comment: That was it!   I've been running Sophos for about 6 months.  This was the first time it causes problems.  Thanks!!!

Comment: That helped me, too! Thanks!!